# is my app still running?

Tags: android

A few months back I started developing an app that read incoming sms messages and saved them in a db.

A few days ago I went to revisit the app and had a quick look in the db where I discovered the app was still recording my texts!?!

I can't find any mention of my app running on the android apps option under settings or in advanced task killer.

I'm pretty certain I just made a normal app, not a service or anything? I must've turned the phone off 10s of times and yet its always running (or so it would appear)

How can I find out if it's running or not? It's bizarre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you probably added an `BroadCastReceiver` for Incoming sms message. This is not service, but your app will always be getting this intent, and u probably end up storing it into DB.

If you dont want this You can uninstall app, by killing from TaskManager wont work in this case.

You probably could not even find this app in running services etc. But you `BroadcastReceiver` will continue receiving messages

Comment: Yes I do have a broadcast receiver. So that will constantly be running, even if the app isn't? I find that very strange!

Comment: no it is not strange, it is what BR created to behave.  if u dont want it like this, u can always register Broadcast receiver in Activity or Service and unregister it when exiting from Activity or Service. You probably registerred receiver in Manifest, which becomes global and runs in different process, nd doesnt depend upon App is running or not.

Comment: Quite possibly. It's not strange if that's what it's supposed to do, I just wouldn't have thought it would work like that. Thanks for your help